# How to delete all excel errors in all worsheets in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

As an office policy, I am required to ensure that there are no errors (i.e. #div,#ref) in any of the excel files. We have a software which lists down all the excel errors.

In few excel files, there are 50 tabs,and each tab has multiple errors.

To remove all excel errors. I press ctrl+c, the ctrl+g (go to) ,the click on special,then check errors in formula. This selects all excel errors  **only in that sheet** and I press delete.Hence all errors are deleted in that tab

Is there anyway,in which all excel errors in **all tabs** can be removed at one go?

Comment: Is this really a programming question? Are you expecting to write VBA for this?

Comment: That sounds like a questionable practice! What if other formulas point at those cells? At any rate, try recording a macro doing it once, and then modify it to loop through each sheet in a workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this small **VBA** macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        sh.Select
        Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Clear
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

this version will work on hidden sheets:

```
Sub Macro1()
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Clear
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hack!Is there anyway,it also selects hidden tabs and deletes errors in them..thanks a lot :)

Comment: No variable declaration, unqualified objects, "On Error Resume Next" as the first line and a `Select`! -1 from me.

Comment: is there anyway in which it deletes errors in hidden tabs as well ? thanks. i googled a bit,in vain

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but please don't do it. Try fixing your formulas so they don't display errors. For example, If you are getting a Div/0 error then check to see if the denominator is 0 before dividing.

Deleting the errors will make the file a nightmare to troubleshoot or work with in the future.

Comment: ya i know....in quite a few files,there are past useless workings,so was finding a way for that...thanks :)

Comment: -1 this is not an answer. It is a comment (along the lines of Doug Glancy's).

Comment: @brettdj: I provided an alternative to the question in searching out the reason for the errors. Not an answer to the direct question, but that would be for the OP to decide, no? (which the OP did by marking the other option as the answer to the question)